# How to call shell commands on bin/sh opened through execl

Tags: c, linux

In my code, I am using execve() to execute a file at a particular location.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE "newFolder/program"

int main() {

    char *n[] = { FILE,  NULL };
    execve(FILE, n, NULL);
    perror("execve");

    exit(1);
}
```

I do not have the complete source code of `FILE` but I know that it ends in the following:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", NULL);
```

Is there a way for me, through my code which calls `FILE`, to execute shell commands (i.e. `ls -la`) on the `bin/sh` that `FILE` opened?

Comment: regarding: `#define FILE "newFolder/program"`  The type `FILE` is defined in the header `stdio.h`  It is not a good idea to be trying to override the the typedef's in a header file that is included in the source code

Comment: you could enter, at the command prompt: `cat|less|more newFolder/program` to get the contents of that file

Comment: regarding: `execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", NULL);`  This will run `sh`.  There is nothing terminating the `sh`, so after running your code, a new shell will be running.  I.E. `sh`  Therefore, anything you type at the command prompt will be run via `sh` until the computer is re-booted or `exit` is typed by you.

Comment: `execve()` will unload - your code will not be running if `execve()` succeeded. There are ways to do certain things like what you want, but if you give us more context - what your program is trying to do, whether or not it's running interactively etc., it will help.